# Overflow attacks with input strings and ret, x86

Tags: x86, buffer-overflow

Before the question, this is purely for an assignment, I am not planning on wrongfully gaining access to insecure programs otherwise.

I have an assignment that involves overflowing an input string so that the `ret` instruction sends me to some address I want to go. The string is expecting 32 bytes maximum so if I fill it with 32 bytes of garbage, then another 4 bytes of garbage, and then 4 bytes of the address I want to visit, then I've manipulated the program to call the wrong function. The reason I fill 4 bytes of garbage after the 32 is because the function that is overflowing the string ends like this:

```
8048bc9: e8 3c ff ff ff     call 8048b0a <Gets>
8048bce: b8 01 00 00 00     mov $0x1,%eax
8048bd3: c9                 leave  
8048bd4: c3                 ret
```

`<Gets>` is what filled the string. If I understand correctly, the 4 bytes of garbage are popped into `%ebp` during `leave`, and then my 4 bytes are executed by `ret` basically as a jump to the function I want to go to.

This was enough to solve simple problems, but in some cases I am supposed to execute additional code before jumping where I want with `ret`. I don't understand `ret` well enough to do this. If I wanted to say set `%eax` to some value (such as 0x12345678), how is this possible from a `ret` instruction that still has to jump to the wrong function?

This is running as 32 bit if that matters. I'm asking how to do additional instruction because the first problems have non-changing addresses but the later problems have addresses that had a random value added to them.

Comment: You'll have to go through a little piece of code that sets `eax` to some value and let that code do the jump to the actual function. The 32-byte buffer should be more than enough to hold that piece of code.

Comment: @harold, So I would have `ret` point to somewhere in the 32 byte string and put code there?

Comment: Well that's the most convenient place to put code, you're putting something there anyway. The address of that buffer is known, right?

Comment: I'm sure I can find it, thank you

Comment: @asimes Yes, definitely. You need to find a piece of code that jumps into your corrupted buffer. For example, if a debugging session shows that the address of your buffer is present in `EBX` upon `ret`, then you need to direct that `ret` to a piece of code that executes a `jmp ebx` or `call ebx`. Of course, things can be even more complex than that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As harold mentioned, the solution was to have the return function send me to the beginning of my string buffer.

This can be done by overflowing the string buffer with 40 bytes (this is 32 bit x86) so that the first 32 bytes are in the string buffer, 4 are popped by the `leave` instruction, and the final 4 are executed by the `ret` instruction. The goal was to make the final 4 bytes be the address of my string buffer in little endian form. After the `ret` instruction executes those 4 bytes my machine code starts to be executed from the beginning of the string buffer.